# Distribute month's quantity equally into weeks

Tags: pandas

Have two data frames:

1) df

```
    Month           Qty
    -------------------
0   2017-10-31      100 
1   2017-11-30      200
```

2) week

```
    Week
    ----------
0   2017-10-01 
1   2017-10-08 
2   2017-10-15 
3   2017-10-22 
4   2017-10-29 
5   2017-11-05 
6   2017-11-12 
7   2017-11-19 
8   2017-11-26
```

How can I equally distribute the Month's quantity across weeks to get the following output:

```
    Week            Qty
    -------------------
0   2017-10-01      20
1   2017-10-08      20
2   2017-10-15      20
3   2017-10-22      20
4   2017-10-29      20
5   2017-11-05      50
6   2017-11-12      50
7   2017-11-19      50
8   2017-11-26      50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `datetimes` to `month` period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) in both `df`.

Then created `Series` for map column `Week` and divide by length of each period created by `transform`:

```
df1['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Month']).dt.to_period('m')
df2['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Week'])

s = df1.set_index('Month')['Qty']
a = df2['Week'].dt.to_period('m')
df2['Qty'] = a.map(s) / df2.index.to_series().groupby(a).transform('size')
print (df2)
        Week   Qty
0 2017-10-01  20.0
1 2017-10-08  20.0
2 2017-10-15  20.0
3 2017-10-22  20.0
4 2017-10-29  20.0
5 2017-11-05  50.0
6 2017-11-12  50.0
7 2017-11-19  50.0
8 2017-11-26  50.0
```

Details:

```
print (a.map(s))
0    100
1    100
2    100
3    100
4    100
5    200
6    200
7    200
8    200
Name: Week, dtype: int64

print (df2.index.to_series().groupby(a).transform('size'))
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    5
4    5
5    4
6    4
7    4
8    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if the first dataframe has repeating values:
<code>    Month           Qty
    -------------------
0   2017-10-31      100 
1   2017-11-30      200 
2   2017-10-31      300 </code>

I get an error called 'InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Comment: It is really problem, because need unique values - cannot use `map`. Can you create new question with this situtation, if not possible use `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('Month')` ?

Comment: `df1.drop_duplicates('Month')` produces an error _ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False_
Wouldn't df1.drop_duplicates('Month') make df1 unique but in the process delete lines with valid quantities also?

Comment: Yes, it lost all dupe data. So maybe better is aggreagation - see my answer in your new question.